# Convert pandas multi index dataframe into a simple dataframe with all index in columns

Tags: pandas

Apologies for the image but I'm not sure how to reproduce this as I was given this data...

[image: Multi index dataframe]

I simply want to convert this into a simple dataframe where I have index columns `time`, `lon`, `lat` and the values in respective rows like so:

```
| time | lat | lon | data |
```

I tried doing .reset_index() but the `time` axis still goes across and not downward. How can I "explode" all the index values to get a simple dataframe with all index in columns?

Edit:

Dictionary of test data for reproducing:

```
{Timestamp('2001-01-01 00:00:00'): {(50.18000030517578,
   -5.6199951171875): -1.68,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.9200439453125): -1.88,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.219970703125): -2.08},
 Timestamp('2001-01-02 00:00:00'): {(50.18000030517578,
   -5.6199951171875): -1.95,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.9200439453125): -2.25,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.219970703125): -2.55},
 Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): {(50.18000030517578,
   -5.6199951171875): -0.76,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.9200439453125): -0.91,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.219970703125): -1.06},
 Timestamp('2001-01-04 00:00:00'): {(50.18000030517578,
   -5.6199951171875): -2.9,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.9200439453125): -3.01,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.219970703125): -3.11},
 Timestamp('2001-01-05 00:00:00'): {(50.18000030517578,
   -5.6199951171875): -2.06,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.9200439453125): -2.29,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.219970703125): -2.52}}
```

Comment: Print result of `df.head(5).to_dict()` from this I can `pd.DataFrame(...) `

Comment: Edited - although I couldn't work out how to preserve index names (to_dict() automatically removes them (?)) - thanks for offering to help.

Comment: I've added solution proposal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp


d = {Timestamp('2001-01-01 00:00:00'): {(50.18000030517578,
   -5.6199951171875): -1.68,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.9200439453125): -1.88,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.219970703125): -2.08},
 Timestamp('2001-01-02 00:00:00'): {(50.18000030517578,
   -5.6199951171875): -1.95,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.9200439453125): -2.25,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.219970703125): -2.55},
 Timestamp('2001-01-03 00:00:00'): {(50.18000030517578,
   -5.6199951171875): -0.76,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.9200439453125): -0.91,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.219970703125): -1.06},
 Timestamp('2001-01-04 00:00:00'): {(50.18000030517578,
   -5.6199951171875): -2.9,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.9200439453125): -3.01,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.219970703125): -3.11},
 Timestamp('2001-01-05 00:00:00'): {(50.18000030517578,
   -5.6199951171875): -2.06,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.9200439453125): -2.29,
  (50.18000030517578, -4.219970703125): -2.52}}


df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.stack().to_frame().reset_index()
df.columns = ['lat', 'lon', 'time', 'data']
```

Output:

```
      lat       lon       time  data
0   50.18 -5.619995 2001-01-01 -1.68
1   50.18 -5.619995 2001-01-02 -1.95
2   50.18 -5.619995 2001-01-03 -0.76
3   50.18 -5.619995 2001-01-04 -2.90
4   50.18 -5.619995 2001-01-05 -2.06
5   50.18 -4.920044 2001-01-01 -1.88
6   50.18 -4.920044 2001-01-02 -2.25
7   50.18 -4.920044 2001-01-03 -0.91
8   50.18 -4.920044 2001-01-04 -3.01
9   50.18 -4.920044 2001-01-05 -2.29
10  50.18 -4.219971 2001-01-01 -2.08
11  50.18 -4.219971 2001-01-02 -2.55
12  50.18 -4.219971 2001-01-03 -1.06
13  50.18 -4.219971 2001-01-04 -3.11
14  50.18 -4.219971 2001-01-05 -2.52
```

Comment: `.stack()` seems like what I was looking for to flatten the row index! Thanks.

Comment: There is one thing to improve: columns name handling, it should done more auto-magically ;-)